# If-Modified-Since HTTP header passed by IE9 includes length?

Tags: asp.net, http, caching, internet-explorer-9, last-modified

#### Please clarify this weird `If-Modified-Since` header passed by IE9

In my ASP.NET 4.0 web app, I've got a generic handler (.ashx) that serves images stored in the DB.  In the interest of efficiency, I'm handling some caching-related headers and passing cache information.

I'm getting DateTime parse errors moderately frequently from trying to parse the `If-Modified-Since` header contents, usually from IE9.  Turns out it's sending something like this:

> Mon, 28 Nov 2011 16:34:52 GMT; length=8799

I'm handling that by using a regular expression to strip out the last part.  But I'm curious: what length is it referring to, and what use is it?  Is it the size of the cached data for the requested URL?

Comment: I'm a little confused. It sounds like you are saying IE9 is sending the `Last-Modified` header, but clients don't usually have any reason to send that header. That is a header that the web server should send to the client. In any case, "; length=8799" is NOT supposed to be part of that header according to the [HTTP protocol specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29), so I would posit that there is some misbehaving code incorrectly setting it somewhere.

Comment: Sorry.  It's the `If-Modified-Since` header.  I'll correct the question.  D'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an [old post](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200307/0122.html) on the Squid proxy mailing list:

> The length parameter to If-Modified-Since is a Netscape extension of 
>   HTTP/1.0, meant to improve the accuracy of If-Modified-Since in case 
>   a document is updated twice in the same second.
>
> HTTP/1.1 solved the
>   same problem in a better way via the ETag header  and If-None-Match.

I'm guessing that IE adapted this extension at some point and have left it in.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old Netscape extension of the header field (see [an ancient discussion on http-wg](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/ange/archives/archives-95/http-wg-archive/1024.html)); even though it seems to actually be against both [HTTP/1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#If-Modified-Since) and [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) specifications (the idea was (functionally) replaced with the ETag header). No idea if/why IE9 sends it and under what specific conditions (I would guess only a specific combination of caching headers triggers it).

I guess the best solution would be to drop anything after a semicolon, which is normally used in HTTP to separate extension parameters in headers (see e.g. [the Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1)).

Comment: Extension parameters only apply to some header fields, and Date isn't one of them.

Comment: Mormegli - just clarifying that parsing for a ";" is something you can *not* do in general with a field value